# AVCaptureStillImageOutput shutter timing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I created an app that uses AVCaptureStillImageOutput from AVFoundation. I realized that in my app and other sample sources, shutter takes 1 second or so to make the sound after the shutter button has been tapped.

Is there a way to make the sound as soon as the button is tapped? I searched and found similar questions but did not find a concrete answer.

[How to avoid shutter sound struggling during capturing still image with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349667/how-to-avoid-shutter-sound-struggling-during-capturing-still-image-with-avcaptu)

[Is there any way to improve time between shots with AVCaptureStillImageOutput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434556/is-there-any-way-to-improve-time-between-shots-with-avcapturestillimageoutput?rq=1)

[How can I mute the capture sound in AVFoundation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557081/how-can-i-mute-the-capture-sound-in-avfoundation?rq=1)

Comment: The shutter sound is synchronized with the actual image capture (which does not happen immediately, and varies according to the ambient lighting). If you were to sound the shutter immediately it would give the user the false impression that the image capture is over, when it isn't, and if they try to capture a new image when the previous one is not complete, you would not be able to process the request. So I think you should think again if you really have a compelling reason to try to change this.

Comment: I get your point. Is it possible then to take the still image as soon as the snap button is tapped then? The built in app does that. I did some research and look sthat with AVCaputreVideo is possible but my guess is that it might loose some quality and I don't want that.

Comment: You can achieve the same speed as the built in App, but that is not instantaneous. For example, try taking a picture with the built in App in a dark room. You will be able to notice the delay between shutter press and picture complete. You should certainly not use AVCaptureVideo to capture a Still image, unless you want a low resolution image.